# Coldfusion 2021 with Microsoft Exchange 365

Tags: coldfusion

i would like to make a connection over microsoft 365 online with cfexchangeconnection to get my emails but I have tried everything and it returned error 401

Is there anyone was successful using cfexchangeconnection with office 365

I am using Coldfusion 2021 Enterprise

Can I have a simple example of code

Sorry I am a newbie to cfexchangeconnection

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cfexchange tag is not compatible with 365 since Microsoft dropped support for basic authentication. You an use the Microsoft Graph API to work with emails.

https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4212511